# How i can setup my Jenkins that can be used in different machines?

Tags: jenkins

How i can setup my Jenkins that can be used in different machines? i want a jenkin to be setup and any one can hit the URL with IP and login with valid credentials. 
The main aim is not to configure jenkins on every colleagues system and they can access my jenkins just through an URL.

Comment: that's how Jenkins works :P if you can login through the browser then anyone should be able to access it(provided everyone's using the same network). I'm guessing your running it locally...if that's the case you will have to expose the port to the internet so that others can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install one instance of Jenkins in a dedicated server, tune it, **secure it** and create the Jobs. After it you can share the IP/Host and the user & password to your colleagues and they can access to Jenkins.

I recommend you to check the installation manual: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/

Comment: i did the same and shared the credentials. But on other machine with correct IP/Host, it's throwing the Login error.